# How can I read and write JPEG data on a per-pixel basis?

Tags: c#, jpeg

The title pretty much explains my question. I would like to be able to read and write JPEG data on a per-pixel basis using C#.

I'm thinking something along the lines of `CreateJPEG(x, y)` which would set up a blank JPEG image in memory, and would give me a JPEG object, and then something like `SetPixel(x, y, Color)` and `GetPixel(x, y)` the latter of which would return a `Color` or something similar. You could then call an `Apply()` or `Save()` method, for example, to save the image in a standard JPEG-readable format (preferrably with compression options, but that's not necessary).

And I'm assuming some C# library or namespace makes this all a very easy process, I'd just like to know the best way to go about it.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when you change a single pixel of a JPEG encoded picture, more pixels of the picture will change due to the non-lossy compression JPEG implements.

Comment: Just a note regarding the JPEG format - as it's a lossy compression, then the colour of an individual pixel may change between saves, even if you didn't directly change it, so don't rely on pixel colours remaining constant EDIT: beaten :)

Comment: Right ;) I was asking because I'd like to try my hand at writing some image comparison software, basically, given 2 images, produce a bitmap of the differences. I know it's been done before, but it'd be good practice for me, and I just needed a quick point in the right direction (something SO is really good for, actually). :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class. For advanced drawing besides manipulating single pixel you will have to use the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class.

```
var image = new Bitmap("foo.jpg");

var color = image.GetPixel(1, 2);
image.SetPixel(42, 42, Color.White);

image.Save("bar.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

As Lasse V. Karlsen mentions in his answer this will not really manipulate the JPEG file. The JPEG file will be decompressed, this image data will be altered, and on saving a new JPEG file is created from the altered image data.

This will lower the image quality because even recompressing an unaltered image does usually not yield a bit-identical JPEG file due to the nature of lossy JPEG compressions.

There are some operations that can be performed on JPEG files without decompressing and recompressing it - for example rotating by 90° - put manipulating single pixels does not fit in this category.

Comment: "Lossless compression"? You mean lossy.

Answer (score 8):

JPEG is not a processing format, it's a storage format.

As such, you don't actually use a JPEG image in memory, you just have an image. It's only when you store it that you pick the format, like PNG or JPEG.

As such, I believe you're looking for the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class in .NET.